# Create a unique show page for 151 different profiles using react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

This is my first time using react router so I'm a little confused on how to go about this. On my home page, I have 151 unique thumbnails of monsters. When the user clicks on one of the thumbnails, I want the user to be taken to the monsters 'show page'. For the monsters href, i'm using its index to create a unique url:

```
{this.props.pokeList.map((pokemon, index) => {
  return (
    <div key={index} className="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
      <a style={aTagStyle} href={index + 1} className="thumbnail">
        <img src={`https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/calpaterson-pokemon/${index + 1}.jpeg`} style={imgStyle} />
        <p style={textStyle}>{pokemon.entry_number}</p>
        <p style={textStyle}>{pokemon.pokemon_species.name}</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  );
})}
```

This is my current routes file:

```
class PokedexRouter extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={ hashHistory } >
        <Route path='/' component={App} >

        </Route>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Creating Route path='/1' all the way up to 151 in my routes file definitely doesn't seem right. The user could also enter a number > 152 after localhost:3000/ in the address bar so how would I prevent that?.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use react-router [Router](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#route-components) params. You can use onEnter to redirect if the user tries to enter a value that is not supported.

```
const validatedImageId = (nextState, replace, callback) => {
    const imageId = parseInt(nextState.params.imageId, 10);

    if(isNaN(imageId) || imageId < 0 || imageId > 151) {
        replace('/'); // redirect to main page
    }

    callback();
};

class PokedexRouter extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={ hashHistory } >
        <Route path='/' component={App} >
            <Route path='image/:imageId' component={ImagePage} onEnter={ validatedImageId } /> // the imageId will be a parameter, that the ImagePage component will receive
        </Route>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

{this.props.pokeList.map((pokemon, index) => {
  return (
    <div key={index} className="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
      <Link style={aTagStyle} to={ `image/${index + 1}` } className="thumbnail"> // use react-router Link component to link to the route
        <img src={`https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/calpaterson-pokemon/${index + 1}.jpeg`} style={imgStyle} />
        <p style={textStyle}>{pokemon.entry_number}</p>
        <p style={textStyle}>{pokemon.pokemon_species.name}</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  );
})}

const ImagePage = ({ params }) => ( // extract the params from the props
    <img src=`https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/calpaterson-pokemon/${ params.imageId }.jpeg`} /> // use params.imageId to get the original index of the image
);
```